# Cinnamon - cursor blocked at end of panel

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop-environment

When I move my cursor along a panel, it eventually is blocked at the end of it. I have two panels, one on the left and one at the top, so I'd like to be able to click the top-left corner. Although, this is not that much of an issue on the desktop, it is still active when I am playing a full-screen game!

[image: picture of the problem]

My cursor (represented by the ugly arrow) cannot go any further than the red line when it is in the blue area.
How can I deactivate this?

Comment: How did you manage that??? The Cinammon does not lock mouse in any way. Most likely you have some application which does it. But usually such apps limiting the cursor by its own window (for example DosBox). Start with a `ps -ax` in the terminal and identify all the app you are having. One of them could be the culprit.

Comment: @WhiteOwl it's easily reproducible. Move the bottom panel to the top (the start menu will be on the top left) and create a new panel on the left side of the screen. Unfortunately, this blockage is still there in LM 21 (Cinnamon 5.4)

Comment: Wow! That does look strange indeed. But the block is only on the top and bottom border of the left panel. Just move the cursor out of it and whole top panel is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is indeed a strange behavior of the mouse.

Adding a bug report.
https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/11038